# Nuxt.js: Client fails in production, but works during development

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using nuxt-edge to serve ssr for an existing rather complicated app. If I run `yarn dev` everything works great, but after building a production version I get only server-side rendered markup (that also looks as it should) and error on the client

```
TypeError: [nuxt] Error while mounting app: n.e is not a function
    at V (cb1f209f20a02940261c.js:2)
    at cb1f209f20a02940261c.js:2
    at w (9664f928831af5328a28.js:formatted:4639)
    at Generator._invoke (9664f928831af5328a28.js:formatted:4617)
    at Generator.t.(anonymous function) [as next] (http://127.0.0.1:3000/_nuxt/9664f928831af5328a28.js:2:83522)
    at r (9664f928831af5328a28.js:formatted:4038)
    at u (9664f928831af5328a28.js:formatted:4052)
    at 9664f928831af5328a28.js:formatted:4057
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at 9664f928831af5328a28.js:formatted:4049
```

I have no idea how to debug minified js transpiled by webpack and babel, maybe I'm missing something obvious. Any thoughts are appreciated

Comment: its impossible to tell what wrong without a minimal reproduction code..

Comment: Enable the creation of a source map so you can debug easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some digging around I've found out that the problem was in dynamic importing routes by webpack.

[Airbnb's babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node) fixes the problem.

To allow pass babel config through .babelrc I've used [nuxt-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-babel)